# Exponential Distribution Rate Parameter With Raise Power of Negative Value

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I am solving an exponential distribution question and I am confused with the given rate parameter. The exponential distribution question is in below:

**Suppose that the length of a telephone call (in seconds) is exponentially distributed with rate parameter $r = \frac{1}{187} {\rm s}^{-1}$ .
Find the interquartile range of a call length**

As I understand the exponential distribution rate parameter is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. However, the given question is $\frac{1}{\lambda}^{-1}$ . May I know what does it mean? I try to search more information about this but I cannot find it from any elsewhere.

Comment: There are two common parametrizations (1) rate parameter in units of "per length" or "per second" (2) scale parameter in units of "length" or "seconds". Here in your context of telephone calls it the first one: the rate given as "$r$ calls per second", where the value of $r$ is a small number $1/187\approx 0.053476$. Don't be fooled by it being written in the form of a rational number (be it $r$ or $\lambda$). It's still a rate (number of calls per second).

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeeDavidChungLin . I still have questions on your comments and please allow me to clarify with you :D

1. I am not so clear about scale parameter in units of "length" or "seconds". Is that possible that you show me that based on my given exponential distribution question?

2. I see the unit $s$ has raise power of -ve 1 (${\rm s}^{-1}$). Does this affect the rate parameter?

3. The computation $1/187$ should be $≈0.0053476$ instead of $≈0.053476$. So do I need to multiply 10 for this?

Comment: Sorry, the $0.0053476$ was just a typo on my part. The $s^{-1}$ simply means "per second", as in "1/second" with a numerator of one and a denominator of a second, which is "one over second".

Comment: The parameter of the your setting can be given as "$\beta = 187$ **seconds**", which the reader would understand that it is a scale parameter that means exactly the same thing as "$r=\frac1{187}\mathbf{\frac1s}$". The literal translation of the former would be "the scale parameter is 187 seconds of talking time per call", which is equivalent to saying the latter "the rate parameter is one call per 187 seconds of talking".